# Zero Rows return on querying DMV sys.dm_os_performance_counters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dmv

I have a user on `SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition (RTM)` with `SYSADMIN` role with Server View State Permissions but when I execute DMV `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` it returns no record.

Any idea what is wrong with permissions?

[image]

Output of @@Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) Feb 20 2014 20:04:26
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on
>   Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Its quite possible that during installation the registry counters are not installed. If user has `sysadmin` permission then he does not require `view server state` permission to run the DMV its included in sysadmin role. In light of above if no rows are returned this means perfmon counters are not installed.

Comment: @Shanky Not always, there are 2 more possible reasons. I've personally had the registry reasons (in a hardened security environment where apparently the registry changes during the installation did not properly go through)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure the user in question has `View Server State` (and it looks like in your screenshot he does).

Then there are a number of reasons previously [put into an msdn blog.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/what-should-we-do-when-the-sql-server-performance-counters-are-missing) Ranging from:

1. Performance Objects and counters set-up during the SQL Server installation failed.
2. A mixture of 64 and 32 bit platforms.
3. Registry permissions have been skewed

To resolve this we can use the same steps outlined in the [guidelines for reinstalling the performance counters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19002/37971) in a different stack-exchange post:

Using an elevated administrator command prompt perform the following steps.

1. Change the path to the `BINN` directory of the SQL Server instance you desire to correct.
   (Ex: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\Binn`)
2. Execute `unlodctr <<REGISTERED SERVER NAME>>`
   For example: `unlodctr MSSQL$SQL2008` or `SQLAgent$SQL2008` ...
3. Execute `lodctr /T:<<perf-sql* matching the counters you desire to load>>`
   For example: `perf-MSSQL$SQL2008sqlctr.ini` or `perf-SQLAgent$SQL2008sqlagtctr.ini` for SQLAgent. The `/T` is important to load the SQL Server performance counter provider as a *trusted provider*.
4. Cycle the remote registry service:
   `net stop "Remote Registry"` then `net start "Remote Registry"`
5. Force a WMI synchronization using `winmgmt /resyncperfctr "<<PID>>"`
   where PID is the process id of the `WinPriv.exe` (you can get this from Task Manager)

The following may also be required:

- Make sure that the correct security permissions have been granted to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009`
  registry key:

  1. Grant Full Control permissions to the Creator Owner account.
  2. Grant Full Control permissions to the Administrators account.
  3. Grant Read permissions to the SQL Administrators on that box/Node.
  4. Grant Full Control permissions to the System account

Comment: this method is for SQL Server 2008 is this same for 2014 ?

Comment: @AA.SC Yes, the method hasn't changed AFAIK.

Comment: @@Reaces client updated his system RTM to SP1 this has resolved the issue.